# How to sort images by date and time in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following script to display images from a directory, but I'm having problems to find information to sort the images by date and time.

This is the script:

```
<?php

  $myDirectory = opendir("fotos/");

  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
  }

  closedir($myDirectory);

  $indexCount = count($dirArray);

  for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -3);
    if ($extension == 'jpg') { 
      echo "<div class='seccion'><img src=\"fotos/$dirArray[$index] \" /></div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I tried $data = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($entryName)); but it can't recover the data

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to detect the $timestamp of the last modification of the image using filemtime and use this value as the key of array and then sort the array by keys using ksort. I runned at Macintosh but it can't recover the timestamp with the function filemtime. Maybe running under Windows it will work, I don't know. In my case all files have the same timestamp and then it appears just the last image detected (because all itens will be the same key). I hope that works under windows, it is just a tentative. I hope that it can help you.

```
  $myDirectory = opendir("fotos/");

  $dirArray = array();
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
      if (substr($entryName,0,1)!='.'){
          $timestamp = @filemtime($entryName);
          $dirArray[$timestamp] = $entryName;
          echo "$entryName $timestamp<BR>";
      }
  }

  closedir($myDirectory);
  ksort($dirArray);

  foreach ($dirArray as $key=>$value) {
    $extension = substr($value, -3);
      echo "$extension $key $value<BR>";
    if ($extension == 'jpg') { 
      echo "<img src=\"fotos/$value \" />";
    }
  }
```